# Cannot Conect to port 9222 using selenium with latest version of chrome

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium-chromedriver

Since chrome self-update i frequently getting this error

Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at localhost:9222
from unknown error: DevTools returned unknown type:shared_storage_worklet

i search and could not found the specific shared_storage_worklet error. Can someone help me?

i didnt found any solution on web for this particular error, its a error with the latest version of chrome.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.